# How to make Jenkins filter files changed in last commit and send them by FTP/SFTP

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have Bitbucket private repository and I have Jenkins installed on a server. I configured project that creates builds when Bitbucket repository gets updated using push. I also configured 'post built actions' to send updated files over FTP/SFTP. Everything works fine except the Jenkins sends entire site to the target FTP account, regardless i pushed a commit with one file changed.

Just to mention that when i go to project/build/changes it lists just the changed files. Seems the 'send build artifacts over FTP' is not aware of that and send entire workspace

In the `project > settings > post build actions > send build artifacts over FTP > Transfer set > Source files` I have set `**`. Do I need to change this value?

Can someone help me set the Jenkins project to upload changed and new files only? It's absurd to upload 2000 files while only couple of files where added/changed.

Answer (score 0):

#### Why this happens?

> Jenkins sends entire site to the target FTP account, regardless i pushed a commit with one file changed.

Each commit is not just the changed files. [It's actually a snapshot](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) of the whole working tree (the project folder). That's probably why Jenkins sends the whole project and not only the changed files.

#### How to filter only the changed files?

There's a way to filter the files, changed by the last commit (or N last commits). Hope this helps you produce a final solution.

This only shows changed files:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only HEAD
```

This is supposed to copy them: (doesn't work for me due to a different OS, trying to port it now)

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:"%h" | xargs -I %id% git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r %id% | xargs -I % cp --parents % upd/
```

Use `-number` instead of `-1` to search through that number of last commits.

#### What to do in Jenkins.

Sorry, don't know the exact way to configure Jenkins yet. But that's what needs to be done:

1. Use the command above to copy changed files into a folder outside of the project.
2. Have Jenkins upload them by FTP
3. Clear the folder for future reuse.

This solution has parts translated from [ru.stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423369/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know where in the Jenkins project configuration I should set these commands. Any hints? Thanks

Comment: That's not for Jenkins configuration. Just open the console, move to your project folder and run it. What is your OS?

Comment: My main problem is Jenkins project that sends all files to the target FTP account. I need it to copy only changed and new files to the FTP account. Jenkins automation is what I am after.

Comment: Oh, sorry, mistook this question for another one, which is really a run-once solution.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Sorry, I'm unfamiliar with Jenkins, don't know how to make it upload a custom folder.